# efi usb boot problems with linux mint 17.2

Tags: boot, usb, linux-mint, efi

I've created a few usb boot sticks for linux mint 17.2 a few different ways (i.e, from both windows & linux) that all work correctly when trying to boot my laptop.

However, when I try to boot my desktop from these, instead of seeing one usb boot option, I see both a usb & a uefi option pop up for the usb stick.

If I pick usb, I get a flash screen for linux mint that counts from 10 to 1 and then the screen goes black and nothing happens.

If I pick the uefi option, I can select linux mint 17.2 from a grub select menu, and again I get a black screen and nothing happens.

The motherboard in question is an asrock z77e-itx.  Intel Rapid start is disabled.  I can't find any safe boot options to disable either.

Any ideas on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!